# Database Vs JSON Vs Embedded Databases

Tags: mysql, database, json, rest, data-structures

I have a web application which has a fair amount of user base. The application currently uses MySQL for storing all the data, be it static or user data. The problem is that I have recognized some data which is never going to change frequently in the database but there is a probability that it might!

I am using REST calls for fetching the data from the database which is in the form of a JSON, the questions in my mind are:

- Should we store the not changing data as static JSON files? I know it will kill the relationship that I could have established with that data.
- Another point is Embedded Databases or in-memory database, are they a good alternative to store not so reverently changing data?

Comment: use any kind of static database kill you for any change. Look a looong time, your data is growing!!! In-memory database are for the most frequently requested data. Are fast. What is wrong with current database?

Comment: the problem is that the current database has a lot of static content which gets requested all the time from the Front-End.. will it be better to shift that frequently accessed data to the in-memory one?

Comment: And i dont know about your security but for current data as you have and put them into a json files, it not make a security risk? And which kind of data are static? Data or texts (translations)?

Comment: i can protect them easily if i put them in json files as static content.. there are certain entities which are there in the database which are used only when a particular module is launched else they are of no use.. its data + translations both

Comment: understand, i would use json for small data, if you have a lot of data then you can use in-memory db. Have a look for http://www.mongodb.org/ or https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding performance, no assumptions are safe. You should **always measure things**, in order to come up with a conclusion. Therefore, in your position I would do some **load testing** and then start changing things. I would reject the file based solutions and suggest the next optimizations/changes to check:

- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/buffering-caching.html) provides some capabilities of "storing information in memory buffers to increase performance"
- I would consider using a NoSQL database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) which is optimized for accessing [JSON data](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/).
- If none of the above were adequate, I would consider using a memory related database like [VoltDB](http://voltdb.com/) which has a [community edition](http://voltdb.com/download/software).

Hope I helped!