# Creating content from JSON vs database - Efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

my first post here. Judging your possible reaction from the title, this post might seem duplicate. I have indeed found these posts: [one](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-articles/javascript-2/javascript-html-generating-html-and-embedding-javascript-in-html/), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275570/database-vs-json-vs-embedded-databases), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elemets-using-js), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297143/dynamically-create-a-html-form-with-javascript), etc, but my question is slightly different. I am making my first website using JavaScript and Bootstrap. I have experience with Java (from coop terms) and C, C++ from school, so still learning what JS is "behind the scenes". Yes, I am still a student.

I have a dataset of about 100-200 objects max. They are small: four fields of type string with maybe 30 chars maximum size. I was wondering if I could get advice and feedback about the design.

**Requirements:**
 - ability for the client to edit the dataset;
 - render new html contents from the updated dataset.

**Design:**
I planned to store as dataset as a JSON file, as array of objects. The client will never have to see it, I almost finished a HTML-based parser/editor for that JSON file. The idea was to parse the JSON, create objects, put them into the array, use array to create HTML content: Page loads: the JSON is parsed and array is loaded. I have access to objects now. Thus, I use another function in JS to create HTML from that new array. The chunk of HTML is about this size:

```
            <!-- product block. copy this to make more-->
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="product-holder">
                <img src="flowers/flower2.jpg" alt="flower1" class="img-rounded flower-preview">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h4>Tulip<small> Latin Name for Tulip</small></h4>
                    <p class="product-descr">This tells what tulip is like. Some useful information</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- product block end -->
```

**My concerns are:**

- hardcoding this much HTML in JS looks like a pain;
- performance of rending might be awful for that many objects;
- JS array of 100-200 objects is unwise performance-wise as well.
- Should I use a mySQL database instead?

This is my first public-to-be website. I enjoy web programming very much. However, I have little experience, but I am trying hard to make it up to the industry standard (as much as possible). So if this is an awful way to go, please let me know.

So far I have the layout done, and I can parse and manipulate JSON data, JSON editor. I am attempting to write qsort in JS (there is probably a library in JS, but it's more for practice) to sort the array alphabetically. So, there are performance implications of that as well.

Thank you in advance for any feedback. Note, I am not looking for any code. Just advice on the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a lot of work to do something which actually very easy to do. Writing code to build the HTML seems like over-kill. I would use a database and look at using some JS framework to do the HTML binding for me. Have a look at AngularJS or Knockout.js.

In terms of efficiency, your dataset is so small at present I don;t think there would be any noticeable differences in either approach.

Comment: Thank you very much chead23. I am a newbie and did not even know about angular. What a fantastic tool! Thank you.